# error in date solve the program

Tags: php, mysql

This is my program :

```
$newEndingDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['startdate']))."+1 year");
echo $newEndingDate;
```

this is my error

```
1332441000
```

whats the error

Comment: That is not an error, that is a timestamp. See [`date()`](http://www.php.net/date) for how to turn it into a readable date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`strtotime()`**](https://www.php.net/strtotime) function returns an [**UNIX Timestamp**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Unix_time) : the number of seconds since 1970-01-01.

The number you are getting is not an error : it just means that 1332441000 seconds have passed since 1970.

If necessary, you can use the [**`date()`**][3] function to format that timestamp, to get a string that looks a bit more user-friendly.

For instance :

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newEndingDate);
```

should get you the following result :

```
2012-03-22 19:30:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [mktime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to do what you want. Assume `$row['startdate'] == '2011-01-01'`

```
$mydate = strtotime($row['startdate']);
$newEndingDate = mktime(date("H", $mydate), date("i", $mydate), date("s", $mydate), date("n", $mydate), date("j", $mydate), date("Y", $mydate) + 1);
echo date('Y-m-d', $newEndingDate); //2012-01-01
```

What you are doing will not give you the result you're after because you can't do the following:

```
strotime('2011-01-01+1 year');
```

Try this instead:

```
$mydate = strtotime($row['startdate']);
$newEndingDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 year", $mydate));
echo $newEndingDate; //2012-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the return value of strtotime function, which is a UNIX timestamp. The seconds passed since 01/01/1970

I think this is you would like to get:

`$newEndingDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ 1 year', strtotime($row['startdate'])));`

Answer (score 0):

you dont get an error, you get the timestamp of all the seconds that have passed since 1970/01/01

if you need a readable format try:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $newEndingDate);
```